# Как сделать тоже самое с помощью адресации?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, память

Задан массив `char str[stolb][dlina];`
а также:

`int length = 0; char s[100];
str[i][j] = s[length];`

Хочу сделать тоже самое с помощью адресации, пишу следующее:

```
*(str+i+j) = *(s+length);
```

Компилятор ругается:

> [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [dlina]'

Что я делаю не так? Не понимаю, как устроен двумерный массив в памяти. 
Прошу объяснить это, а также рассказать на данном примере, что я делаю неправильно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите сами - если бы ваша запись была верна, то `str[1][5]`, скажем, было бы обязано быть равно `str[5][1]`. Двумерный массив располагается в памяти построчно - в вашем случае `dlina` элементов `str[0]`, `dlina` элементов `str[1]`, и так далее.

Так что делать то, что вы хотите, нужно примерно так:

```
const int stolb = 3, dlina = 5;
char str[stolb][dlina];
int length = 0; char s[100];
int i, j;
*((char*)str+i*dlina+j) = *(s+length);
```

Comment: а  так  *(str[0]+i * dlina + j) = *(s + length); не получается?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можно, но мне кажется, что так несколько затеняется, что ли, смысл операции - она оказывается привязана к `str[0]`, а не к `str` в целом.

Comment: интересно,  всегда интересно ваше мнение...

Answer (score 1):

`n`-мерный массив — это одномерный массив, элементами которого являются `n-1`-мерные массивы.

В вашем случае, `str` на самом деле является одномерным массивом из `stolb` элементов, которые в свою очередь являются одномерными массивами из `dlina` элементов типа `char`.

Чтобы "добраться" до элемента двумерного массива можно рассуждать следующим образом.

Если у нас есть двумерный массив:

```
str
```

То мы можем получить указатель на `i`-тый элемент этого массива, т.е. указатель на массив из `dlina` элементов типа `char`:

```
str + i
```

Разыменовываем предыдущий указатель, т.е. получаем массив из `dlina` элементов типа `char`:

```
*(str + i)
```

Именно на этом этапе у вас и возникли затруднения. С помощью кода `*(str+i+j) = *(s+length);` вы пытаетесь присвоить объекту типа массив, объект типа `char`. Так делать нельзя, о чём вам и сообщил компилятор.

Продолжим "добираться" до элемента двумерного массива.

Если у нас есть массив, то мы можем получить указатель на `j`-тый элемент этого массива, т.е. указатель на `char`:

```
*(str + i) + j
```

Ну и наконец, имея указатель на `char`, мы можем его разыменовать, т.е. мы можем обратиться к объекту типа `char`:

```
*(*(str + i) + j)
```

Таким образом, эквивалент записи

```
str[i][j] = s[length];
```

выглядит так:

```
*(*(str + i) + j) = *(s + length);
```